# How does hunspell works

Tags: hunspell

I looked for a paper which explains how does hunspell works, but without any success.
I would like to know how does `hunspell` works and especially how does it make suggestions ? Does it uses `Levenshtein distance` to look for the best suggestion ?

Thanks